# add live ID to BODY with PHP

Tags: php, document-body

I'm using the php code:

```
<body id="<?php echo str_replace("index.php?","",(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],".php"))); ?>">
```

and

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['start'])){
     include('includes/start.php');
    }else if(isset($_GET['help'])){
     include('includes/help.php');
    }else{
     include('includes/start.php');
    }
?>
```

It works great - cutting index.php?help to "help" and index.php?start to "start" in body ID. But when I enter index.php in body ID is "index" not "start". Is there any way to tell index.php with included start.php to display "start" id body ID?

**UPDATE**

It should work dynamically - body ID is name of included .php file, something like this code:

```
<?php 
   $page = str_replace(array( 'server_name', 'index', '?',  '/', '.php'), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $page = $page ? $page : 'start';
?>

<body id="<?php echo $page ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure i get you 100% but you can try

```
$id = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$bodyID = $id;
switch ($id) {
    case "help" :

        include ('includes/help.php');
        break;
    default :
        $bodyID = "start";
        include ('includes/start.php');
        break;
}

printf("<body id=\"%s\"  >", $bodyID);
```

If you run `index.php?help` it would include `include ('includes/help.php');` and also output

```
<body id="help"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use this instead:

```
<?php
    $ids = 'start,help,something';
    $ids = explode(',',$ids);
    $included = 0;
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        if (isset($_GET[$id])) {
            include('includes/'.$id.'.php');
            $included = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$included) include('includes/'.$ids[0].'.php');
?>
```

Then:

```
<body id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Comment: rationalboss Your solution works great (Baba thank You for reply as well) but I wanted to do it dynamically - body ID is from name of included .php file

Comment: made it dynamic, it defaults to the first entry if nothing is set

Comment: rationalboss You code is still great, but way too complicated :-) Is there any way to use my simple code with basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to display index.php with ID "start" in body?

Comment: I believe the code I gave you is better. Relying on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` isn't good. For instance, when the page is `index.php?start&something_users_can_add&blah=1`, the ID would be `start&something_users_can_add&blah=1`. With the above code, you only need to edit `$ids` when adding IDs. You may try to cut everything off after the `&` BUT if the user puts `index.php?help&start`, the include file will be `start.php` and the ID would be `help`.

Comment: I am not convinced after all :( Your code inserted above <body> tag loads page outside my wrapper. If I put it below <body> inside wrapper then body ID is unknown (Notice: Undefined variable: id) :-/

Comment: then you need to put the code further top before the `<body>` tag

Comment: But when I do that, included content is showing outside wrapper in index.php :-/